# Replacing a certain part of string with a pre-specified Value

Tags: puppet

I am fairly new to Puppet and Ruby. Most likely this question has been asked before but I am not able to find any relevant information.

In my puppet code I will have a string variable retrieved from the fact hostname.

```
$n="$facts['hostname'].ex-ample.com"
```

I am expecting to get the values like these

```
DEV-123456-02B.ex-ample.com, 
SCC-123456-02A.ex-ample.com, 
DEV-123456-03B.ex-ample.com, 
SCC-999999-04A.ex-ample.com
```

I want to perform the following action. Change the string to lowercase and then replace the 
-02, -03 or -04 to -01.

So my output would be like

```
dev-123456-01b.ex-ample.com, 
scc-123456-01a.ex-ample.com, 
dev-123456-01b.ex-ample.com, 
scc-999999-01a.ex-ample.com
```

I figured I would need to use `.downcase` on `$n` to make everything lowercase. But I am not sure how to replace the digits. I was thinking of .gsub or split but not sure how. I would prefer to make this happen in a oneline code.

Comment: Note that your output isn't fully in lower case. I don't know if that's intentional.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It is supposed to be all lowercase. I edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Puppet and Ruby are entirely different languages and the other answers are for Ruby and won't work in Puppet.

What you need is:

```puppet
$h = downcase(regsubst($facts['hostname'], '..(.)$', '01\1'))
$n = "${h}.ex-ample.com"
notice($n)
```

Note:

- The downcase and regsubst functions come from stdlib.
- I do a regex search and replace using the regsubst function and replace `..(.)$` - 2 characters followed by another one that I capture at the end of the string and replace that with 01 and the captured string.
- All of that is then downcased.

Comment: Thank you Alex . This is what I was looking for. However, would you suggest some online resource which would explain regsubst with examples. I am not able to find good documentation on this.

Comment: @tafz, there's a whole blog about it here http://akxc.github.io/2017/01/09/puppet-string-substitute-with-regsubst.html

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a one-liner, you could run this against each string:

```
str
  .downcase
  .split('-')
  .map
  .with_index { |substr, i| i == 2 ? substr.gsub(/0[0-9]/, '01') : substr }
  .join('-')
```

Without knowing what format your input list is taking, I'm not sure how to advise on how to iterate through it, but maybe you have that covered already. Hope it helps.

Comment: The same result can be achieved using the following regex: `str.downcase.sub(/\A((?:[^-]*-){2})0[0-9]/, '\101')` which selects 2 times any amount of non-`-` characters followed by a `-` character and places them in group 1. It then matches `/0[0-9]/`. The replacement sets back group 1 followed by `01`.

Answer (score 1):

**If the `-01`-`-04` part is always on the same string index** you could use that to replace the content.

```
original = 'DEV-123456-02B.ex-ample.com'
#                  11 -^

string = original.downcase # creates a new downcased string
string[11, 2] = '01' # replace from index 11, 2 characters
string #=> "dev-123456-01b.ex-ample.com"
```